# How to remove bathroom sink faucet handle?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, sink, leaking

Need to fix a leaking bathroom sink faucet. Managed to remove the handle. How to get the cartridge out? I can’t seem to remove the handle base, nor remove the nut that holds the cartridge in place. What can I try? Other than calling the plumber  I won’t give up just yet.

[image: handle base]

Comment: What have you tried to remove the nut?  Could it be left-handed?  Have you tried a lubricant like Liquid Wrench or it's equivalent?

Comment: +1 to penetrating oil — let it sit for a while.

Comment: You might also be able to unscrew the escutcheon and drop the whole thing underneath and out, which might make disassembly more easy.